# use Identity value in entity after insert in Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc

i want to generate value using current date and ID of inserted entity
problem is that ID value not generated until insert object to  database,
so i use this code for generate value:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,TrackingCode,FirstName,LastName,ProductName,CurrentStats,FailureReason,ReceiveDateTime,DeliveryDateTime,Price,Description,SerialNumber,ExtraItems,PhoneNumber")] Tracking tracking)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Trackings.Add(tracking);
            db.SaveChanges();
            Tracking _tracking = db.Trackings.Find(tracking.ID);
            db.Entry(_tracking).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _tracking.TrackingCode = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + tracking.ID.ToString());
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(tracking);
    }
```

code work fine and do job that i want
but i think this is not standard way is there any better approach to improve this code?

Comment: Off-topic: this is not a review task but a question how to solve a programming problem. Your current code doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @GertArnold code work fine and do what i want , but i think this is not standard way

Comment: *problem is that ID value not generated until insert object to database* So your code doesn't work the way you want it to work. You want it to do it all in one transaction. Also, it's not clear what `ToPeString` does.

Comment: @GertArnold ToPeString is just extension Method

Comment: @GertArnold actually, that's pretty standard when you rely on the database to provide ids (as you should because it has better facilities for highly concurrent insertions). As such the question is IMO on-topic

Comment: @Vogel612 That's not my point. My point is: I would never say that the code works *fine* because if the second `SaveChanges` fails the database content is inconsistent. For me, this is a Stack-Overflow question because the code must be *fixed*.

Comment: @GertArnold my code work fine, i just need review!

Comment: Are you using SQL Server with EF?

Comment: @CharlesNRice yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you change your database design.

Option 1)

Have SQL Server set a column to the current date/time when you insert a row  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6594589 for how to do it.  Then have that column mapped on your Tracking entity but mark the property as [[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Assuming you call the field AddDate

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public datetime AddDate {get;set;}
```

Now you can create your get only TrackingCode property in code and use the [[NotMapped]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) on it and define it as

```
[NotMapped]
public int TrackingCode 
{
     get { return Convert.ToInt32(AddDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + tracking;
}
```

Option 2:

Create an after insert tigger and have SQL Server update the TrackingCode.  Again I would mark the property as DatabaseGenerated

In a nut shell it's better to offload this to the SQL Server

Comment: why add DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed to datetime?? i have problem with ID value

Comment: That tells Entity framework to retrieve the field but don't update the field as the database will be the one to generate the value and not the entity.

Comment: why Propery dont have setter and you just put getter only?

Comment: IF you go with option 1 you have sql update a new column.  I called it add date.  Then you just make a calculated property to use in your code.  If you actually want the value to be in a column in SQL then I suggest you do option 2